# Pourquoi ne peut-on pas dire : « échouer à + infinitif » ?

Tags: usage, verbes, synonymes

On peut dire

> J'ai réussi à rencontrer mon ami.

ou

> Je suis parvenu/arrivé à résoudre l'exercice.

En revanche, en googlant et sans faute de ma part, on voit qu'on ne peut pas utiliser "échouer à faire quelque chose", à savoir, dans le sens de l'anglais "fail to do something". Pourquoi ne peut-on pas le faire ? Je me demande, par exemple, pourquoi la phrase suivante est considerée gauche :

> Elle a échoué à sauver son fils.

et qu'on doit utiliser la négation de réussir ou parvenir/arriver.

On lit ici http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2007/06/01/5190954.html

> Le Lexis (1977) **reçoit** la construction échouer à faire quelque chose,
> que je ne rencontre cependant pas ailleurs :
>
> **Le drame de l'enfant qu'il avait échoué à sauver (Beauvoir)**.

Source pertinente

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-%C3%A9chouer-%C3%A0.2534099/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La construction ***échouer à* + infinitif** est ancienne et utilisée par de bons auteurs.

> 1736
>   […] l’autorité publique ayant **échoüé à arrêter** […]
>   [*Mercure de France*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k63550567/f59.image.r=%22%C3%A9chou%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20arr%C3%AAter%22)
>
> 1780
>   […] elle a **échoué à faire** le rôle de Colette […]
>   [*Mémoires secrets pour servir à l’histoire de la république des lettres en France*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6531909c/f311.image.r=%22%C3%A9chou%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20faire%22)
>
> 1815
>   Si j’**échoue à me maintenir** sur le trône […]
>   [*Amours secrètes de Napoléon Bonaparte*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k61308305/f12.image.r=%22%C3%A9choue%20%C3%A0%20me%20maintenir%22)
>
> 1827
>  
>   […] ont **échoué à vouloir** représenter par des formules la gradation […]
>   [*Mémoires de l’Académie des sciences de l’Institut de France*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k32227/f780.image.r=%22%C3%A9chou%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20vouloir%20repr%C3%A9senter%22)
>
> 1849
>   […] ils ont constamment **échoué à les reconstituer** […]
>   *Journal de Seine-et-Marne*, 3 mars 1849
>
> 1866
>   S’il **échoue à le devenir** lui-même, c’est par un mélange singulier d’audace, de superstition et d’incertitude.
>   Larousse, [*Grand dictionnaire universel du XIXe siècle*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Grand_dictionnaire_universel_du_XIXe_si%C3%A8cle/Wallenstein,_trag%C3%A9die_en_cinq_actes_de_B._Constant)
>
> 1908
>   […] puisqu’on **échoue à les prévoir** […]
>   Bergson, [*Essai sur les données immédiates de la conscience*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Essai_sur_les_donn%C3%A9es_imm%C3%A9diates_de_la_conscience/Chapitre_III)
>
> 1910
>   On pense à corriger la nature, quand on **échoue à la révéler**.
>   Suarès, [*Voyage du Condottière*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Voyage_du_Condotti%C3%A8re/Texte_entier)
>
> 1920
>   […] même un esprit comme celui de Voltaire **échoue à rassembler** ces fragments […]
>   Lanson, [*Histoire de la littérature française*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_litt%C3%A9rature_fran%C3%A7aise_(Lanson)/Cinqui%C3%A8me_partie/Livre_3/Chapitre_2)
>
> 1962
>   Si l’homme **échoue à concilier** la justice et la liberté, alors il échoue à tout.
>   [Camus, *Carnets*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9chouer/27522?q=%C3%A9chouer#27376)

---

Quant aux liens que vous donnez, je ne vois pas ce que l’on peut en tirer :

- Le premier s’avoue lui-même non concluant ;
- Le deuxième est mort ;
- Le troisième et le quatrième donnent des avis contradictoires non étayés.

---

Accessoirement, pour ceux qui considèrent que cette construction est incorrecte, pourquoi attribuer son origine à l’anglais ? [Le français dit aussi bien *faillir à* + infinitif](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faillir), et [c’est *faillir* qui a donné *fail*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fail).

Answer (score 6):

Chose lue dans le Monde :

- L’UE échoue à adopter la neutralité carbone en 2050.

Cet anglicisme commence à s'imposer dans la presse française.  La phrase n'est donc pas fausse, mais elle est perçue négativement par certains locuteurs natifs, dont je suis.  Ceci dit, si ce n'est dans cette langue un peu particulière qu'est le langage des journalistes, je ne me souviens pas d'avoir entendu employer ailleurs cet *échouer à + infinitif*.

Comment: Voici une citation pertinente : "le drame de l'enfant qu'il avait échoué à sauver  (Beauvoir).

Comment: Effectivement!  Peut-être que ma perception est à mettre sur le compte d'une idiosyncrasie.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Cependant n'étant pas locuteur natif je ne comprends pas pourquoi ça c'est considéré comme anglicisme et de plus pourquoi on peut dire  réussir à +  infinitif et on ne peut pas le faire pour échouer. C'est pas logique☺, non ?

Comment: C'est peut-être moi seul qui considère ça comme un anglicisme et qui suis heurté par cette tournure.

Comment: C'est effectivement une construction relativement récente, mais je ne vois pas ce qui permet d'affirmer qu'elle serait influencée par l'anglais. C'est un calque naturel de « réussir à » et « renoncer à ».

Comment: @Gilles C'est que je sens le "fail to" d'un usage beaucoup plus fréquent en anglais derrière "échouer à + infinitif".  J'ai quasi toujours l'impression quand je le rencontre dans des articles de journaux de lire une dépêche d'agence traduite à la va-vite.  C'est intéressant de voir que ce sentiment n'est pas partagé.

Comment: @Gilles Selon http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2007/06/01/5190954.html  Le Lexis (1977) reçoit la construction échouer à faire quelque chose, que je ne rencontre cependant pas ailleurs :

Le drame de l'enfant qu'il avait échoué à sauver. (Beauvoir.)

Donc ce n'est pas assez récente, je trouve:-)!

Answer (score 3):

Je ne vois aucun mal à utiliser cette formulation bien qu'elle soit peu ou pas usitée. Comment en es-tu arrivé à une telle supposition ?

Il est vrai qu'on dira plutôt "n'est pas parvenu à + infinitif".

Pour reprendre ton exemple :

> Je suis parvenu à résoudre l'exercice.
>
> Je ne suis pas parvenu à résoudre l'exercice.

Comment: Merci. Gouglant un peu et vous verrez que "échouer à + inf" est considéré pas acceptable et fautive.

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement je ne me servirais pas de cette façon d'utiliser le verbe « échouer » et m'en tiendrais au « mode » connu, c'est à dire à l'usage de tournures un peu plus longues ;

- Elle a échoué dans sa tentative de sauver son fils.
- L'UE échoue dans son projet d'adoption de la neutralité carbone en 2050.
- Ils ont échoué dans l'opération de connexion des robots.

Le commentaire très intéressant trouvé [ci-dessus](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37755/pourquoi-ne-peut-on-pas-dire-%c3%a9chouer-%c3%a0-infinitif#comment75644_37757) donne à penser. Il semblerait exister une certaine logique tendant à vérifier l'usage tel qu'il a été préservé jusqu'à nos jours, mais cette logique serait elle jugée pertinente —elle n'est que le fruit de mes réflexions—, elle  consiste en un raisonnement si ténu, serait il juste, que l'on préfèrera peut être ne pas en tenir compte ; je tente de l'expliquer ci-dessous, vu que l'idée pourrait être vérifiée par d'autres et leur plaire. Elle semble cependant justifier les tournures un peu plus longues du français. Si l'on se rapporte à la définition de « échouer » dans le TLFi,

> « Au fig. [En parlant d'une pers. ou de ce qu'elle a entrepris ou produit] Se heurter à un obstacle social, moral ou intellectuel et ne pas réussir à le surmonter; subir un échec. », [d'autres devraient être ajoutés : obstacle technique, naturel,… (user **LPH**)]

on voit que ce qui est entrepris ou produit n'est pas directement impliqué, ce n'est que la tentative, que le projet de la chose qui l'est, c'est à dire une série de stages à passer avec succès ou parmi lesquels être arrêté par un écueil ;

Cela est un peu plus explicite dans le dictionnaire de [l'Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/%C3%A9chouer?page=1) ;

> Fig. (ne s'emploie en ce sens qu'avec l'auxiliaire Avoir). En parlant d'une personne. Ne pas réussir dans une **entreprise**, une action. N'entreprenez pas cette réforme, vous y échouerez. Il a échoué dans ses efforts pour rétablir la paix publique. (user **LPH**'s bold type)

« Sauver son fils », par exemple, n'est pas l'opération de sauvetage de son fils mais le résultat de celle-ci, c'est le sauvetage en tant que résultat ; on verra peut être cela dans les phrases suivantes ;

- Sauver son fils, c'est tout ce qui comptait. (*Le sauvetage de son fils, c'est tout ce qui comptait.*)
- Sauver son fils avait couté cher à l'état.  (*La vie sauve de son fils avait…*)
- Finalement elle n'avait fait que sauver son fils, incapable de secourir sa fille. (*« Elle n'avait fait que travailler au sauvetage » n'aurait pas de sens; elle avait obtenu le résultat.*)

« Échouer » signifie « être arrêté » dans une étape du processus, mais il n'y a pas de processus impliqué dans un résultat, alors que le verbe réussir signifie

> « [Avec un adv. précisant le sens] Aboutir à un résultat (bon ou mauvais). »

où « aboutir » veut dire

> (TLFi)  « Se terminer dans; arriver; ».

On ne dira pas couramment par exemple « Ils ont réussi *dans* l'opération de sauvetage; » mais tout simplement « Ils ont réussi l'opération de sauvetage. » parce que le verbe « réussir » sert à exprimer un état final, celui du succès à un point donné, à la fin d'un processus. Cela est encore le cas pour « Ils ont réussi à sauver son fils. » (*Le résultat est confirmé.*)

Comment: Suivant cette théorie, on ne dirait pas non plus « renoncer à ».

Comment: @Gilles Je ne saisi pas ce qui est contraire au principe ; La renonciation serait dans le manque de conformité d'une  étape dans un processus ; ça ne semble pas être une relation « directe » possible ; qu'il y ait coexistence avec celui-ci, ou par exemple l'apparition d'un raisonnement impliquant cette étape et menant à la décision de renoncer (à continuer) serait une situation qui  reste dans le domaine du réel ; le fait de  décider prend forme non dans et par l'étape directement mais dans la pensée et porte non pas sur le processus  mais sur un de ses attributs ('être continué ou non).